# Overriding heightForRowAtIndexPath makes cell return unexpected black background

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm overriding the `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method for the first cell in first section. However, doing so makes unexpected black background on the cell appear. This doesn't happen if the method is not overridden or just simply `return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;`. After inspection, that black bar comes from `selectedBackgroundView`, but why? It has bugged me for hours now, what's going on?

[image]
Not overriden

[image]
Overriden

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
            switch (indexPath.row) {
                case 0:{
                    return 100.0f;
                    break;
                }
                default:
                    break;
            }
    }
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellID" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    
    if (cell == nil || cell.detailTextLabel == nil ){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle  reuseIdentifier:@"cellID"];
    }
    
    cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.imageView.image = nil;
    cell.textLabel.text = nil;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = nil;
    switch(indexPath.section) {
            case 0:{
                switch (indexPath.row) {
                    case 0:{
                        
                        NSAttributedString *myText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Test"];
                        
                        UILabel *trackInfoLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:cell.contentView.frame];
                        trackInfoLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
                        [trackInfoLabel setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
                        [trackInfoLabel setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
                        trackInfoLabel.attributedText = myText;
                        
                        [cell.contentView addSubview:trackInfoLabel];
                        break;
                    }
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Try setting clipsToBounds to true in the cell view.

Comment: Not helping unfortunately.